# login test failing in Python Flask unit test

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing, flask

I am trying to test the login functionality for my Python Flask app.

I create a user and add them to the database in the `test_adduser()` test and that passed fine. However, the `test_login()` test fails with an assertion error. I have debugged the code and the test loads the login page ok (so I know the problem is not with the app or the routes etc) but it does not log in and redirect the user.

I realise that this post is a bit short on description i.e. the error trace, however the error is literally "AssertionError". 
Maybe I am doing something obviously wrong, like the way I am passing in the user credentials to the test and someone could point this out to me?

Thanks!

```
from flask.ext.testing import TestCase
from flask import Flask
from Shares import db, app as appy
from Shares.models import User
import manage


class test(TestCase):

def create_app(self):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['TESTING'] = True
    return appy

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = "sqlite://"
TESTING = True

def setUp(self):

    manage.initdb()
    #print self.login('lucas', 'test').data

def tearDown(self):

    db.session.remove()
    db.drop_all()

def login(self, username, password):
    return self.client.post('/login', data=dict(
        username=username,
        password=password
    ), follow_redirects=True)

def logout(self):
    return self.client.get('/logout', follow_redirects=True)

def test_adduser(self):

    lucas=User(username="lucas", email="lucas@example.com", password="test")
    user2 = User(username="lucas", email="lucas@test.com")

    db.session.add(lucas)
    db.session.commit()

    assert lucas in db.session
    assert user2 not in db.session

def test_login(self):
    lucas=User(username="lucas", email="lucas@example.com", password="test")
    db.session.add(lucas)

    rv = self.login('lucas', 'test')
    assert 'Welcome' in rv.data
```

Comment: You reset your database between tests. Unless `manage.initdb` inserts a user, you have no users to log in for `test_login`.

Comment: Thanks, manage.initdb did add a user but I have edited the code here to clarify that.

Comment: If `manage.initdb` adds a user that matches the user in `test_login`, `test_adduser` should violate a constraint on username. Also, `test_adduser` doesn't actually test your application; it tests SQLAlchemy. SQLAlchemy has its own tests. You don't need to test it as part of your test suite.

Comment: Thanks, sorry I was unclear, originally the user was added in manage.initdb() but I moved that into the test file to make it clearer. I accidentally omitted that from this code so it wasn't clear.

The edited code above is what I have now but it still does not work.

Thanks for the headsup for the SQLAlchemy testing, I am sure you can see I'm a bit of a n00b here so that is something I will definitely look into :)

Comment: What's the value of rv.data?

Comment: It returns the HTML for the login page

Comment: @RyanO'Donnell It returns the HTML for the login page

Comment: So it isn't redirecting? Is there a Flashed error on the page? Can you do some debugging and ensure you're not getting a user invalid after the POST?

Comment: @RyanO'Donnell Thanks for the tips.
1. It isn't redirecting
2. There is no flashed error (though I have these implemented)
3. I've debugged and it appears that the 'username' value is passed to the form but the 'password' value is not.
4. I have noticed that the errors list has the following value: {'csrf_token': ['CSRF token missing']}.
Though there is a CSRF token present in the form varible ''csrf_token'

Thanks

Comment: @RyanO'Donnell  Either the form should submit successfully and redirect to the index page or it should reload with the error. The fact that there are no flashed error messages present suggests to me that the form is not even being submitted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so I worked it out in the end. I needed to deactivate the CSRF protection. This did the trick:

```
def create_app(self):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    appy.config['TESTING'] = True
    appy.config['WTF_CSRF_ENABLED'] = False
    return appy
```

Comment: Not sure how you figured this out, but it helped me a lot.

Comment: Disabling of WTF CSRF check helped me as well. Thanks